# BarLegend tick labels broken with MaTeX

Tags: legending, labeling, matex

There appears to be an issue with using `MaTeX` text on the ticks of a `BarLabel`. Without `MaTex`, the alignment is correct:

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", Ticks -> {{0.5, 0}}]
```

gives

[image: not broken]

whereas

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", Ticks -> {{0.5, MaTeX[0]}}]
```

gives

[image: Broken]

Clearly in the second image the tick label is not aligned with the tick.
Does anyone know of a workaround for this issue?

Comment: which version are you using? On V 13.0.1 "Ticks" does not seem to be supported as It shows in Red. Also I get same result with MaTeX. Here is screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6f5N.png)  I also do not see `Ticks` option listed in help for it.

Comment: @Nasser it seems like an undocumented option for `Ticks` --- [`example here`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163583/control-the-tick-marks-in-barlegend). I just tried the accepted answer on `V12` and the result is as expected -even though `Ticks` is in red.

Comment: For me, it's aligned - I'm on V12.3. I'm experiencing an issue that Mathematica doesn't show one tick for me, but if I add more, everything seems fine. Example code `BarLegend[{Hue, {-1, 1}}, Ticks -> (Table[{i, MaTeX@(i*Pi/4)}, {i, -1, 1, 1/4}])]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Hmm, I'm on V12.0 and @mszynisz's code gives me the same problem. I will try updating to the latest version of Mathematica and see if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Method` option (obviously, right?) and the `MaTeX` option `ContentPadding -> False`, which is described in the `MaTeX` documentation:

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", 
 Method -> 
  Ticks -> {{0.5, MaTeX[0, ContentPadding -> False]},
            {0.25, ""}, {0.75, ""}}]
```

[image]

It doesn't work exactly right with just one tick (missing tick mark).

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", 
 Method -> Ticks -> {{0.5, MaTeX[0, ContentPadding -> False]}}]
```

[image]

Note `Ticks -> {{0.5, MaTeX[0, ContentPadding -> False]},...}]` works without `Method` in front of it as well, even though it seems to be a deprecated usage.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything unfortunately!

Comment: That problem with one tick only must be a bug. I wonder if it works on the newest version.

Comment: @ArthurMorris Could you check which version of MaTeX do you have? Run `PacletFind["MaTeX"]` to see. I have v.1.7.8.

Comment: @mszynisz Yes, probably a bug. It happens with `BarLegend["Rainbow", Method -> Ticks -> {0.5}]`, too.

Comment: @ArthurMorris I think your problem is with V12.0, and how it handles `Graphics` labels, perhaps. I don't have V12.0, so I can't check. :(

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think they are using V12.0 (comment under OP's question). I'm using 12.3.

Comment: @ArthurMorris If it's any help, it looks like it's aligning the *bottom* of the graphics returned by `MaTeX` with the tick mark. You probably want the center to be aligned, along with `ContentPadding -> False`, although that will make only a slight difference.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I have updated Mathematica from V12.0 to V13.0 and the problem issue no longer appears. In case anyone cares, the problem appeared when I had Mathematica V12.0 and MaTeX V1.7.8.